# Set Error Message in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the `form_validation` config file to set the validation rules, but is it possible to also set the error messages in there as well? I tried setting an associative array, but it didn't work. The validation itself works, but it says:

> "Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Username."

```
array(
        'field' => 'username',
        'label' => 'Username',
        'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_dash_space|min_length[4]|max_length[25]|is_unique[User.username]',
        array(
            'required' => 'You have not provided a {field}',
            'is_unique' => 'This {param} already exists',
            'alpha_numeric_dash_spaces' => 
              'The {field} may only contain alphanumeric characters, underscores, dashs, and spaces'
        )
    )
```

Or do I have to manually set the error messages in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get that message is because CodeIgniter is looking up `form_validation_lang.php` and not matching anything in there for your rule.

As far as I'm aware your only options are to create a new file at `application > language > ** language ** > form_validation_lang.php` and add your messages there in the format below and CodeIgniter should pick them up.

I've not tested that however but if that doesn't work - although I'm pretty certain it will - then add additional lines in `system > language > ** language ** > form_validation_lang.php` with something like:

```
$lang['alpha_numeric_dash_spaces'] = 'The {field} may only contain alphanumeric characters, underscores, dashs, and spaces';
```

Or you set the message manually in the controller with:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_numeric_dash_spaces', 'The {field} may only contain alphanumeric characters, underscores, dashs, and spaces');
```